# Two left outer joins not summing correctly

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, left-join

I am trying to have 2 LEFT JOINS, SUM the results, and minus one sum from the other. One is summing correctly, but when I put two joins, one of them doesn't sum properly.

```
    SELECT
    j.jobNumber, j.customerID, j.costDelivery, j.costCallout, j.costLabour , 
    c.customerID, c.firstName, c.lastName , 
    IFNULL(sum(jp.amount),0) AS Total_Paid , 
    IFNULL(j.costDelivery,0) + IFNULL(j.costCallout,0) + IFNULL(j.costLabour,0) + IFNULL(sum(p.unitPrice*p.quantity),0) AS Total_Cost
    FROM s_jobcards AS j 
    INNER JOIN s_customers AS c ON j.customerID = c.customerID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN s_payments AS jp ON j.jobNumber = jp.jobNumber 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN s_partOrders AS p ON j.jobNumber = p.jobNumber
    GROUP BY j.jobNumber
    HAVING Total_Cost > Total_Paid
```

The `Total_Paid` column illustrates that the sum of `jp.amount` is incorrect. However, `Total_Cost` sums correctly. Any ideas?

Comment: This is an invalid SQL statement. (MySQL does some unpredictable tricks...) The general GROUP BY rule is: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Comment: ...an exception is when grouping on the pk of the core table.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: @Strawberry, True! However, my tip is still to follow the general rule - then you'll never mess things up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT j.jobNumber, j.customerID, j.costDelivery, j.costCallout, j.costLabour, 
       c.customerID, c.firstName, c.lastName, IFNULL(jp.payment, 0) AS Total_Paid , 
      (IFNULL(j.costDelivery, 0) + IFNULL(j.costCallout, 0) + IFNULL(j.costLabour, 0) + IFNULL(p.cost, 0)) AS Total_Cost
FROM s_jobcards AS j 
INNER JOIN s_customers AS c ON j.customerID = c.customerID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT jp.jobNumber, SUM(jp.amount) payment 
                 FROM s_payments AS jp 
                 GROUP BY jp.jobNumber
               ) AS jp ON j.jobNumber = jp.jobNumber 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT p.jobNumber, SUM(p.unitPrice * p.quantity) cost 
                 FROM s_partOrders AS p 
                 GROUP BY p.jobNumber
               ) AS p ON j.jobNumber = p.jobNumber 
GROUP BY j.jobNumber
HAVING Total_Cost > Total_Paid;
```

Comment: Note that COALESCE conforms to the standard. It's also prettier and more flexible.

Comment: This looks like it should work correctly, but an explanation of why this works and OP did not would provide a better answer.

Comment: This works perfectly! Thanks for your assistance. I was actually thinking of doing it this way but didn't as I thought it would give the same result. Are you able to explain why it's different?